# document.location to first child <a> tag not working in ie6 & ie7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser

i have this HTML code :

```
<ul id="mainlynav">
<li><a href="#">text1</a>
    <ul class="subnavul">
        <li>
            <a href="a.php">Link to a</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="b.php">Link to b</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="b.php">Link to b</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li> 
<li><a href="#">text2</a>
    <ul class="subnavul">
        <li>
            <a href="d.php">Link to d</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="e.php">Link to e</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="f.php">Link to f</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li></ul>
```

i want to when user clicks on one of top level links (text1 or text2) , page go to the first child link (in case of text1 page should go to "a.php" )
so i write my script this way :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mainlynav a[href="#"]').click(function(){
        var DOM = $(this).siblings('.subnavul').first();
        var DOM2 = DOM.children('li').first();
        var DOM3 = DOM2.children('a').first();
        document.location=DOM3.attr('href');
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

this whole proccess works fine in all modern browsers
but in IE6 & 7 , it's not working!

what's the problem?

thanks in advance.

Comment: try with `window.location` instead of `document.location`. The latter is non-standard and deprecated.

Comment: also try adding `.href` to the end. (ie `window.location.href` or `document.location.href`)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté not helped :(

Comment: Make sure you're using a jQuery version which supports old IE too. (1.x and not 2.x)

Comment: @Spudley not helped too :(

Comment: @FabrícioMatté it's 1.7.2 ,

Comment: Do you really need support that far back?

Comment: In that case I don't see anything else that could go wrong with the posted code.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP my taskmaster wants it this way

Comment: I'd say to check the JS console but an actual IE6 doesn't have one, and I guess IE7 doesn't either.. talking about not having consoles, make sure you don't have any `console.log` calls in the code or it'd result in an error. Just a random shot.

Comment: They do display errors in the bottom left corner though, and you could install the firebug js plugin to your page (does it still exist? haven't used it in years)

Comment: @KevinB Yes, Firebug Lite can even be used as a bookmarklet if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mainlynav a[href="#"]').click(function(){
        var url = $(this).next('.subnavul').find('a').first().attr('href');
        if(url) {
            document.location.href = url;
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Note, you don't need `.first()`

Comment: Nor the selector filter for `.next()` (though that probably makes things more readable).

Comment: i don't know why , i tried window.location,window.location.href,and document.location.href before , but this code works ! thanks

Comment: @user2711520 Most likely your way of selecting the first anchor tag was the culprit. That or `DOM` possibly being reserved? who knows.